# ArrayList accessor method returns no values

Tags: java, arraylist, accessor

This is my first program that I am making out of my own class.  It is meant to perform a single-transferable election; right now I need to get an `ArrayList<Candidate>` of `Candidate` objects.  Inside the constructor, the process works just fine; however, once I try to use an accessor method an empty `ArrayList` is returned.  Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Election {

    public ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

    Election(int numVotes) {
        String name;
        ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the candidates you want in the election.");
        System.out.println("Enter -1 once you have listed all the candidates.");
        System.out.print("Start entering candidates: ");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
        while (!name.equals("-1")) {
            candidates.add(new Candidate(name));
            System.out.print("Ok, enter a new candidate or -1: ");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();

        }

        //Works fine here
    }

    public ArrayList<Candidate> getCandidateList() {   
        //Keeps returning empty list
        //System.out.println(candidates);
        return this.candidates;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new ArrayList variable in your constructor, instead you should do
`this.candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();`

Also, it's bad practice to have all your logic in your constructor, you should instead make an `addCandidates()` method

Answer (score 2):

```
public ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
Election(int numVotes)
{
    String name;
    ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are creating a *different* arraylist and "shadowing" the `candidates` member variable.  It should be

```
    this.candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
ArrayList<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
```

you define a local variable that hides the class member. Drop that line.